# Book series about a guy who wakes up with no memory in a world with superheroes and villains

Tags: story-identification, books

I am looking for a book I read last year and have the following information; unfortunately I forgot the title and author.

The story is about a guy who wakes up with no memory. He finds himself in a world like his own, he thinks, but with superheroes and villains with powers. He soon finds out he is not who he thinks he is, but rather a scientist who created a new kind of virus, only to be infected by it and turned into a living, thinking virus that has to eat people to survive.

He has powers and is a bit of an antihero. He only kills bad guys and finds he has powers like speed and strength and gives himself the name 'Revenant'. He works with a young girl, called Bug, who can (surprise) control bugs, and finds out she can control him as well.

That is about all I know of the book series, so I would be very pleased if someone here knows which books they are and can help.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. If anyone correctly identifies the book or series you're looking for, you can mark that answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Comment: Thank you will do, i really hope this Works i have tried everywhere else.

Comment: Hmm... why did you roll back all of the fixes made to your post?

Comment: Please don't undo edits which improved your post (fixing capitalization, etc.). In particular, do not change the tags -- it is important that the tags on the question are correct so that users can more easily find questions like this one.

Comment: Sorry i Clicked it by mistake i just wanted to see what was changed and must have clicked it wrong.

Comment: Some similarities to George R.R. Martin's *Wild Cards*. There is [a character called Revenant](https://wildcards.fandom.com/wiki/Revenant) with super powers, and they do result from a virus. But it's not a virus he had any hand in creating, and apparently his powers are solely telepathic in nature.

Comment: Thanks but that´s not it, i have Read Wild Cards and i was not impressed, to be Honest i find R.R. Martin overrated and Underwhelming.